# insert LI to a UL from an existing UL using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I am having 2 UL and one button

```
<ul class="droptrue ui-sortable" id="sortable1" style="min-height: 128px; mozuserselect: none;"
        unselectable="on">
        <li id="article_1" class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
            Article #1</li>
        <li id="article_2" class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="checkbox" id="2" />
            Article #2</li>
        <li id="article_3" class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="checkbox" id="3" />
            Article #3</li>
</ul>


<ul class="droptrue ui-sortable" id="sortable2" style="min-height: 128px; mozuserselect: none;"
        unselectable="on">
        <li id="article_4" class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="checkbox" id="4" />
            Article #4</li>
        <li id="article_5" class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="checkbox" id="5" />
            Article #5</li>
        <li id="article_6" class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="checkbox" id="6" />
            Article #6</li>
    </ul>

<input type="button" id="add" value=">>" style="width: 15px" onclick="AddToList()" />
```

now on button click i need to remove the corresponding li form "sortable1" and insert it into "sortable2"

I wrote the  function like

```
function AddToList() {
        var vals = $('#sortable1 input:checkbox:checked').map(
         function() {               
             $("#sortable2").append($(this).parent().html());
             $(this).parent().remove();
             return this.id;
         }).get().join(',');                        
    }
```

but this function removes the li but adding only the checkbox into the other ul. if i give $(this).parent().parent().html() which adds all the li to the other ul.Please tell me what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `appendTo` method.

```
 var vals = $('#sortable1 input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() { 
     $(this).parent().appendTo('#sortable2');
     return this.id;
 }).get().join(',');
```